# Conversion from active to passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

The agent with **by** is omitted in passive voice when it is implicit.

I was doing an exercise in which I had to change the sentence

> He kept me waiting

into the active voice. According to me the active voice is

> I was kept waiting by him

but in the solution **by him** is omitted. **Him** can not be omitted because it specifies a particular person. It may be an opportunity also like

> I was kept waiting by this opportunity.

What I want to ask is why **by him** should be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You have things wrong.

> He kept me waiting

is already active voice

> I was kept waiting (by him)

is already passive voice.

"By him" is optional from a grammar point of view, but it adds information to the meaning.

Comment: Ya I know that unknowingly I wrote opposite of what was there in the book. Sorry for that.    But what about assessment????

Comment: the "assessment" was about an older version of the answer

Comment: I have deleted my earlier comments, as they have been addressed. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I was kept waiting by him.

The part "by him" doesn't add any information or value to the sentence which is in the passive voice. *I'm sure you  know that as you wrote it correctly in your question title.*

And the action in the passive voice should become known when adding the "by ___" section which won't be achieved if you add "by him" as the person would still be anonymous. That's why it is better been omitted.

But if it was a person's name, for example. Then you would be right in your explanation for the need for its existence.